# how to get value of element which have particular class and id?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to get transform attribute of particular id and class using java script not jquery? is there any solution to select a specific element, specifying both the class and id ?
for example:

```html
<g id="748588" transform="translate(44 -4)" class="Selection"></g>
```

And I want to get transform attribute corresponding with match id and class

Comment: If your element has an ID that is all you need in order to use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) because the ID is required to be unique.

Comment: for more info take a look https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: @Harish—please don't reference w3schools, its content is very ordinary and has misleading information. MDN or the real W3C are much better (though MDN has references to relevant standards so is often all you need).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document.querySelector()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

```
const selector = document.querySelector("#748588.Selection")
const transformValue = selector.getAttribute("transform")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `document.querySelector` will do what you want.  [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is the MDN page.  In your case, you could use something like:

```
const my_transform = document.querySelector('#748588.Selection').getAttribute('transform')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the element, then you can get the `transform` property from the elements `style` object:

```
document.getElementById("748588").style.transform
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @ Nic3500, you are right, i added additional context